# AWS Lambda can't parse zipped jars

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jar, zip, aws-lambda

When I upload a .zip-file containing a .jar-artifact to an AWS Lambda function, the artifact isn't parsed correctly. However, if the artifact is uploaded directly without being zipped, it works as intended.

The error I get in the lambda console when testing a zipped function is the following:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Class not found: foo.bar.Class",
  "errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
}
```

I must repeat that I am absolutely certain that the artifact when unzipped does *not* display this behavior. It *only* happens when the artifact is zipped.

Comment: Why do you zip a JAR file? A JAR is a ZIP file!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose AWS CodePipeline insists on zipping the output it builds. I suppose I could just unzip it before doing anything with it, I just wanted to not introduce too many steps. It seems likely that Lambda just treats the zip file as a jar file, leading to my problem. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Is your handler or function name by chance not named correctly?

Comment: @PrestonM I solved the issue by forgoing zip files, and therefore CodePipeline, altogether. From what I could find in various documentation and developer forum posts, CodePipeline will always zip its output, and .jars can't be parsed if zipped. By creating a standalone CodeBuild build project and making it trigger on commit to GitHub, I achieved the same functionality I originally sought through CodePipeline, but with the ability to customize my output properly.

Comment: Ok glad you solved your issue! I'm still kind of confused of how that ties in to Lambda, but you should post your solution as an answer none the less!! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that AWS Lambda simply can't parse zipped Java artifacts. I couldn't find any workaround, so the solution is to not zip your .jars in the first place.